# C# .NET DocX Add an Image to a .docx File

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, docx

I want to add an image to a Word file in C# using the [DocX Library](https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX). The problem is that I don't find anything in the web.

**Situation**

I know how to create a file and I know how to write text in the file. The documentation of the library is sadly pretty small. Hope you can help me!

Comment: Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6c2ce499-0454-4b9e-b8d0-19d6350ae8dd/c-word-2010-paste-in-image-and-move-behind-text?forum=worddev) answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The DocX library contains a [sample](https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX/blob/master/Examples/Program.cs) demonstrating how to add a picture to a document:

```
var myImageFullPath = "C:\tmp\sample.png";
using (DocX document = DocX.Create(@"docs\HelloWorldAddPictureToWord.docx"))
{
    // Add an image into the document.    
    Image image = document.AddImage(myImageFullPath);

    // Create a picture (A custom view of an Image).
    Picture picture = image.CreatePicture();

    // Insert a new Paragraph into the document.
    Paragraph title = document.InsertParagraph().Append("This is a test for a picture").FontSize(20).Font(new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS"));
    title.Alignment = Alignment.center;

    // Insert a new Paragraph into the document.
    Paragraph p1 = document.InsertParagraph();

    // Append content to the Paragraph
    p1.AppendLine("Check out this picture ").AppendPicture(picture).Append(" its funky don't you think?");
    p1.AppendLine();

    p1.AppendPicture(picture);

    // Save this document.
    document.Save();
}
```