# How to add header and footer using Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation

I want to add a string which has html tags as a header for a word document generated dynamically using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. The string I want to add is like below

```
"<div style=\"display:block;max-width:750px; margin:0 auto; \"> <img src = \"logo-header.jpg\" style= \"max-width:100%;\" /></div><p></p>"
```

I was able to achieve this using aspose. But because of budgeting issues I dont want to use aspose. Is this possible using office.interop.word?

Comment: Can I ask why you are using Microsoft.Office.Interop?
Im working on a POC which pertains to word document generation.
I am using [openXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) and [exceed DOCX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/).
Seems to have all the functionality I require. I recommend checking out these libraries.(BOTH FREE)
The main reason i ask is, the server/machine that will be running the code will require word to be installed.
Just keep that in mind ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to share code snippets using openXML? @TCP

Comment: May I ask why you need to insert HTML?
As per your HTML string you are adding an image.
I am using DOCX to insert my images.
See example of the code [here](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX/blob/master/Examples/Program.cs)

Comment: Sorry wrong link see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658848/c-sharp-net-docx-add-an-image-to-a-docx-file)

Comment: In the Footer i have to insert text with inline style, so i wanted to know how can i insert html string in the header and footer. Is this possible with OpenXML?

Comment: Please help me with the code of OpenXML to load the document from html string. @TCP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171596/discussion-between-tcp-and-ashita-shah).

Comment: It's not possible to insert HTML into a Word document, directly, and have it come out as Word formatting. HTML is not a "native" Word format. If you place it on the Clipboard it can be inserted as Word content via the Interop using the Paste method. Otherwise, you need to use the OOXML file format, either on the closed file or, using the Interop, with the InsertXML method. Or you can save the image as a file then insert it using the Interop's InlineShapes,AddPicture method.

Answer (score 0):

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article says the following:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.
>
> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You may consider using [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or any third-party components designed for the server-side execution (for example, Aspose).

Comment: I implementing the same using Open Xml. In open Xml how can i insert html string in the header using open xml?

Comment: Microsoft doesn't recommend a lot of things that many of us do every day.  This is not an answer to the question.  It should be included as a comment or note on a proper answer, not as an "answer" in of itself.

Comment: Do you want to say that Office automation works on the server-side without issues?